# Commands order getting changed in unix script

Tags: shell-script

I have below lines in unix script;

```
list_table_name=`hive -e 'show tables from schema'| grep -i 'hst_*' |sort -r|head -1`
```

When executing the script order of the commands is getting changed.

Sometimes the order is coming as

1. `hive -e 'show tables from schema'`
2. `grep -i 'hst_*'`
3. `sort -r`
4. `head -1`

but sometimes the order is coming as

1. `hive -e 'show tables from schema'`
2. `sort -r`
3. `head -1`
4. `grep -i 'hst_*'`

Why this is happening?

Comment: Order of commands getting executed. My intention is to execute hive -e 'show tables from schema' then grep -i 'hst_*' then sort -r then head -1.  But sometimes this is getting changed.

Comment: Note that the commands in a pipeline are launched at the same time, or rather there is no deterministic order. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511243/bash-pipe-execution-order. Why do you need to start `hive` before `grep`?

Comment: All the processes in a pipeline are (in principle) started *simultaneously*. That is a race condition, which means whatever tool you are seeing their order in (maybe consecutive pids in `ps`) notices them in a random order. The actual data flow is always correct because the pipes are created and fds assigned before the processes are executed.

Comment: @Gopi Is there anything that makes you think the final result (i.e. the value stored in `list_table_name`) is affected by the order the commands in your pipeline are executed?

Comment: Yes @fra-san, I see different results than the expected ones.

Comment: How did you determine in which order the commands were started up? What is the difference in the results? Please edit your post to include this information.

Comment: @Gopi  "I see different results", but we *dont*. We see your interpretation of some event which you don't actually post. Are you claiming `list_table_name` contains multiple lines, in spite of the `head -1` in the pipeline? Please, show me an actual command, and its verbatim output, that contains the four lines you list.